# Permission error when trying to parse API using requests.get in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to parse some data from an API URL. When I open the URL in my browser I can see the data I'm looking for. But when I try to open it on python using the requests model, I get an error saying I don't have permission to access it.

Code:

```
import requests
url_screener = 'https://www.otcmarkets.com/research/stock-screener/api'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url_screener, headers=headers, stream=True)
print(response.text)
```

Error:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>
 
You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;otcmarkets&#46;com&#47;research&#47;stock&#45;screener&#47;api" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;1cc68848&#46;1677748437&#46;31cb4c51
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I tried using proxies as well, but that didn't' work. I'm expecting to be able to see the same data in python as when I open the URL in my browser.

Comment: Yes I can access it on the web browser, just not through Python.

Comment: You probably forgot to add the access token in your python request. I would recommend you to read the API Documentation and look for all the parameters that you need to provide.

Comment: The thing is this was working till yesterday without any access token, not sure what happened. I guess I'll try to reach out to them to see if they added any restrictions.

Comment: Figured it out. I had to add 'accept-language' to the headers and it worked. Not sure why this came up after it had been working for a few weeks.
         'accept-language': 'en-US,en-CA;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,hi-IN;q=0.7,hi;q=0.6'

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this in the future: Adding the `accept-language` parameter into the headers worked for me.

```
import requests
url_screener = 'https://www.otcmarkets.com/research/stock-screener/api'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
**'accept-language': 'en-US,en-CA;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,hi-IN;q=0.7,hi;q=0.6'**}
response = requests.get(url_screener, headers=headers, stream=True)
print(response.text)
```